# Scaffolding MVC Controller - how to indicate dataValueField and dataTextField?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

One of the overload methods of SelectList (from the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering namespace) is defined as:

```
public SelectList(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField);
```

When I scaffold an "MVC Controller with view, using Entity Framework" and I create my CRUD pages, I may see the following method inside of my Controller:

```
public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewData["Continent"] = new SelectList(_context.Continent, **"ContinentID", "ContinentID"**);
            ViewData["Country"] = new SelectList(_context.Country, **"CountryID", "CountryName"**);
            return View();
        }
```

The field supplied to the dataTextField parameter is different between Continent/Country. How does MVC/EntityFramework decide which field to supply to dataTextField when scaffolding a Controller? Is there something in the individual models or in the DbContext that I am overlooking? I'd like for the dataTextField of Continent to be "ContinentName" so that I don't have to change it manually in the future when I need to delete and then re-scaffold the Controller.

---

Edit:

Here are the model definitions:

The Model of the Controller that I posted above:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Project.Models
{
    public partial class ProjectForm
    {
        public int ProjectFormID { get; set; }
        public int ContinentID { get; set; }
        public int CountryID { get; set; }

        public virtual Continent ContinentNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual Country CountryNavigation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The one that displays the "CountryName" in the dataTextField the way that I want to see it:

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public partial class Country
    {
        public int CountryID { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ProjectForm> ProjectForm { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The one that displays the "ContinentID" in the dataTextField the way that I do NOT want to see it:

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    public partial class Continent
    {
        public int ContinentID { get; set; }
        public string ContinentName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ProjectForm> ProjectForm { get; set; }

    }
}
```

There is nothing obviously different to me in the model definitions unfortunately.

Comment: Can you add your model code?

Comment: I have modified the question to include model code

Comment: Hmm, I don't see anything there.  I can say that I've seen a lot of quirks and weird things over the years with the scaffolding and the automated stuff they try to do under the hood.   You could try moving some of the problem code to a new solution, and trying to see if you can recreate the problem there or if it goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this post today (a bit late), but see it still hasn't been answered.

While I can't say why the scaffolding chose to use one field over another in your scenarios (unless you initially had your class/model written differently the last time you cleaned/built your project), I can say how to force it to use a specific column.

Add the DisplayColumn attribute to your class. You will need to rebuild before scaffolding again for the change to take.

```
namespace Project.Models
{
    [DisplayColumn("ContinentName")]
    public partial class Continent
    {
        public int ContinentID { get; set; }
        public string ContinentName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ProjectForm> ProjectForm { get; set; }

    }
}
```